# appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, how handle quick action when view is not created yet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, quickaction

Ok, so in my AppDelegate, I initialise various stuff in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, however I create my views in `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

My reasoning behind this was that when the app is executing stuff in the background (push notifications), the `didFinishLaunching...` will be called so I don't want to create UI stuff there, if the application will not be visible.

This has worked for me, however now with quick actions, say i want to have a quick action that goes to one of my tabs. I can't do it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, since the views won't be created until `didBecomeActive`.

So, my questions are:

1. Have I misunderstood something regarding the lifecycle and timing of UI and `didFinishLaunching...`/`didBecomeActive`? That is, is it good practice to do what i do, create the views to be used in `didBecomeActive` and not `didFinishLaunching...`?
2. I haven't really found any good examples regarding this. I suppose i could store away the `UIApplicationShortcutItem` in `didFinishLaunching...` and then use it in `didBecomeActive`. It seems a bit 'hacky', but i haven't figured out anything else.

Pointers much appreciated.

Comment: Hi guys, huge thanks for replying. @originaluser2 i hear you but its not like that. I only init them once. I basically check if i need to switch view every time after that, due to how the app works. Question: what happens if app is launched in "background" fetch, and then is launched for user view? Will didfinishlaunching get called again?

Comment: Exactly. And then i don't see how i would want to create my ui code there only if not running in background mode. If i skip the UI creation due to it being launched in background, but the same process later is used to start it proper, it will fail since i skipped creating the ui before?

Comment: @Cristik oops, I guess I was thinking about the push notification launch key... weird there isn't one for background fetches...

Comment: Right. Then i just need to act on my UIApplicationShortcutItem in the end of didBecomeActive... i suppose i'll have to do what i outlined in #2 above and store it in a property in didfinishlaunching... and use it in didbecome active.